# Reversing a string. Element versus whole string and without built-in functions

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, reverse, function-definition

I'm doing an exercise where I need to reverse the elements of a string e.g. HelloWorld - dlroWolleH

My original code was here as below:

```
std::string reverseString(std::string text)
{
    std::string new_string = "";
    int index = 0;
    int pos_text = text.size();

    while (index <= text.size()) {
        new_string[index] = text[pos_text]; //Line doesn't work.
        pos_text--;
        index++;
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

However, looking online, the code block inside the while loop goes like this instead.

```
new_string = new_string + text[pos_text];
```

Could someone explain to me why it needed to be as the line above?
I was under the impression that a string is an array of characters?

Comment: You are off-by-one. A string of `size()==5` has 5 characters at indexes 0 through 4; but not at index 5.

Comment: `new_string` is empty. `new_string[x]` exhibits undefined behavior for all values of `x`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds. You either need to resize the string to the expected size up front, or (as you discovered) append to it as you go.

Comment: You could use `for(auto it = text.rbegin(); it != text.rend(); ++it) new_string += *it;` or if you don't like iterators: `for(size_t idx = text.size(); idx--;) new_string += text[idx];`

Comment: `std::string reverseString(std::string text) { return std::string(text.rbegin(), text.rend()); }`

Comment: ... or just `return {text.rbegin(), text.rend()};` :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain to me why it needed to be as the line above? I was under the impression that a string is an array of characters?

Actually, strings are dynamic arrays who's size is not fixed. They have the `+` operator overloaded so you can append two strings using `str1 += str2`. For example, `"hello" + "world" == "helloworld"`

When you create `new_string`, you create an empty string so you cannot access any of its elements, because it has none. That's why you need to use `+=`, to append an element.

Note: In practice, you should use `std::reverse(string.begin(), string.end())` instead of a custom algorithm. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: `std::string` is a dynamic string with no fixed size. C-strings (like `"hello"`) are arrays of characters with a fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

You declared an empty string

```
std::string new_string = "";
```

You could equivalently write

```
std::string new_string;
```

So you may not use the subscript operator for an empty string to change its content

```
new_string[index] = text[pos_text];
```

Also in the right operand of the assignment there is also used an invalid index expression `pos_text`. You have to use the expression `pos_text - 1`. Otherwise the character '\0' will be written in the first position of the new string.

Instead you could write

```
new_string += text[pos_text - 1];
```

or (as the same )

```
new_string.push_back( text[pos_text - 1] );
```

As for this statement

```
new_string = new_string + text[pos_text];
```

that again must be written like

```
new_string = new_string + text[pos_text - 1];
```

then for the class std::string there is defined the overloaded operator + with the right operand of the ty[e `char`.

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>
operator+(const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& lhs, charT rhs);
```

Pay attention to that the condition of the while loop

```
while (index <= text.size())
```

is incorrect. You have to write

```
while (index < text.size())
```

The simplest way to define the function is the following

```
std::string reverseString( const std::string &text )
{
    return { text.rbegin(), text.rend() };
}
```

If to use loops as you are doing then the function can be defined like

```
std::string reverseString( const std::string &text )
{
    std::string new_string;
    new_string.reserve( text.size() );

    for ( auto i = text.size(); i != 0; )
    {
        new_string += text[--i];
    }

   return new_string;
}
```

Comment: Optimization: As you using indexing, there's no need to iterate through all the characters in the string. Just replace index 0 with n -1, 1 with n-2 and so on. So basically you are iterating through half the characters in the string

Comment: @Asesh Note that `text` is `const` so in order for your suggestion to work, one would have to copy `text` into `new_string` first, then apply your algorithm.

Comment: @Asesh The function creates a new string without  changing the source string.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the **+** sign in strings, it appends the character to the end of that string. We call this in programming **"Operator Overloading"**.

Example:

```
string word1 = "Hello";
string word2 = "World";

word1 = word1 + word2;
```

The `word1` here becomes `HelloWorld`.
There are diffrent ways to type this `word1 = word1 + word2` line of code, looking online you can see it as `word1 += word2`, This also works and gives you the same result.

Here is a solution for reversing a word too:

```
string reverseString(string word)
{
  int size = word.length();
  string revWord;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    revWord += word[size-i-1];
  }
  return revWord;
}
```